# Netbeans selection problem?

Tags: java, netbeans-6.9

How can we back to a the previous type or method after opening 
a method or type using ctrl + click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't `ALT + Left Arrow` help?

Answer (score 0):

```
Ctrl+Shift+Up/down
```

i think this works for eclipse

Comment: This duplicates a line, I think:)

Comment: Ah, you meant eclipse! He originally asked for NetBeans and I didn't read your post correctly. By the way in Eclipse it is like in NetBeans - `Alt + Left Arrow`

Comment: @Minchev : u were right.`Alt + Left Arrow` works well in eclipse too.Mine is to move b/w methods in an order.just tried it.